# preposition for ''book'' and definite article for book names

Tags: prepositions, articles, indefinite-article

I want to know which of the following sentences are right. say, It's an instruction that a teacher gives. there are several books so the teacher has to refer to one specific book.

I've heard '' page 1 of the book''. but I'm not sure.

> - 1-A)  Please review unit 1 **of** **(the)** English Result/Workbook
> - 1-B) Please review unit 1 **in** **(the)** English Result/Workbook
> - 2-A) Please do the exercises on pages 20,21 **of** **(the)** English Result/Workbook
> - 2-B) Please do the exercises on pages 20,21 **in** **(the)** English Result/Workbook

Answer (score 1):

All your sentences are correct and understandable.

The use of *the* indicates there is a specific "English Result/Workbook" which everyone understands what it is.

The use of either *of* or *in* is appropriate in your cases.

Comment: Thanks. English Result is our course book so everybody knows what I'm talking about and there's only one English Result and only one Work Book. In this case, should I use ''the''?

Comment: Yes, "**the** English ResultWorkbook" is correct.  If you had a pile of the books on a table and each student would need to grab one to use it then "**one of the** English Result / Workbooks" / "**an** English Result / Workbook" would be appropriate.

Comment: I found a sentence that read '' chapter one of Sophie's World'' so I thought maybe we shouldn't use ''the'' with books' names. Is it right?

Comment: One would not usually add "the" to a title.  The title is a specific case of a name and will usually already have "the" in it.

Comment: ''English Result'' is the title like ''Sophie's World'' and they don't have ''the'' in their names. that's why I think I shouldn't add ''the''. I'm confused!

Comment: I see. "English Result / Workbook" is probably not the formal name of the book.  It might be "Oxford English Result / Workbook" or "Bantam English Result / Workbook" where "Oxford" or Bantam" is the publisher's name.